# Is there a method to find the length of a geodesic length from its parameterisation and 'velocity'?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, geodesic, general-relativity

I am attempting to implement [this, pages 11/12](https://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/DEproj/Sp99/PaulC/mypaper2.pdf) method to plot geodesic equations on the surface of an object, beginning with the sphere. I would like to be able to guarantee that the geodetic length of my drawn geodesics are constant for all initial conditions after one time step.

More specifically, the method describes a way to solve the geodesic equations given an initial point and a velocity at that point in local coordinates. I have found experimentally that depending on the initial point and velocity, the length of the drawn geodesic changes. I would like to know if there is a way to guarantee that the geodesics are of constant length, regardless of the starting point, by choosing my initial velocities in such a way. Alternatively, can explain perhaps explain how different start points and velocities would change the length of a geodesic over one time step? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A curve that satisfies those differential equations must have constant speed (but need not have speed $1$). Thus, to get the same length geodesics for a given time step, you must choose the *initial* speeds to be the same. You compute the square of the speed by taking $E(u')^2 + G(v')^2$, so make sure these quantities are always the same. The starting points should not matter; of course, when you compute the initial speed, you need the values of $E$ and $G$ at your starting point.

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks! Just to clarify, this should also be true for surfaces other than the sphere, where the curvature is not necessarily constant?

Comment: Yes, but remember, as the author emphasized, that those formulas only work for an orthogonal parametrization. (See any differential geometry text, e.g., my own free one linked in my profile, for the general case.)

Comment: When you’re satisfied with the answer and have no further questions, please accept the answer so that the question will not remain on the unanswered list.